# Replace occurences of key->values pairs in String

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a map, where I store key->value pairs of parameters which I want to replace in a string.
e.g. Map(id -> 1, name -> peter) & https://example.com/#id/#name should result in this string: https://example.com/1/peter

This is my code so far and it works. Is there any way to make this work without a `var`?

```
def replaceUrlParams(url: String, params: Map[String, String]): String = {
    var replacement: String = url
    params.map(value => {
        replacement = replacement.replaceAll("#"+value._1, value._2)
    })
    replacement
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for `foldLeft`:

```
 params.foldLeft(url) { case (str, (key, value)) =>
    str.replaceAll("#" + key, value)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Regex and [`replaceAllIn`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex@replaceAllIn(target:CharSequence,replacer:scala.util.matching.Regex.Match=%3EString):String):

```
def replaceUrlParams(url: String, params: Map[String, String]): String = {
  val placeholder = raw"#(\w[\w\d]*)".r;
  placeholder.replaceAllIn(url, paramMatch => {
    val key = paramMatch.group(1);
    params(key) // Return the value of params[key] as the replacement.
  });
}
```